# Query if Shoutcast Server is Offline or Online with PHP

Tags: php, offline, shoutcast

I'm trying to use a script to query if a Shoutcast Server is online or offline. The code below is what I'm using at the moment.

```
$vt_ip = "ip";
$vt_port = "port";

$output = @fsockopen($vt_ip, $vt_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

if (!$output) {
echo "<FONT CLASS=f1 COLOR=#DD0000><B>OFFLINE</B></FONT>";
} else {
echo "<FONT CLASS=f1 COLOR=#00DD00><B>ONLINE</B></FONT>";
}

@fclose($output);
```

But it doesn't update, it is stuck on Offline status.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should consider properly handling `fsockopen` just putting an `@` there to suppress errors isn't going to magically make your code work when an does error occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vt_ip = "ip";
$vt_port = "port";

$conn = fsockopen($vt_ip, $vt_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

if(!$conn){
    echo $errno;
}else{

fwrite($conn, "\n");
$output = fread($conn, 1024);
fclose($conn);

if ($output == "") {
    echo "<FONT CLASS=f1 COLOR=#DD0000><B>OFFLINE</B></FONT>";
} else {
        echo "<FONT CLASS=f1 COLOR=#00DD00><B>ONLINE</B></FONT>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, as for the fwrite, $output and fclose, lines are all giving me this error "supplied argument is not a valid stream resource"

Comment: Then it's likely not connecting properly, I've edited the code to show errors(if any).

Comment: Then it's not able to reach the server. Check your ports are open and that it's querying on the correct port/IP.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't enough to simply make a TCP connection to a SHOUTcast server to determine if the stream is working.  In fact, a SHOUTcast server that is running will always accept yourTCP connection, even if there is no stream for playback.

You must connect, request the stream, and then check the return status code.  Once connected, send this data:

```
GET /; HTTP/1.0
```

Follow that by a `\r\n\r\n`.  Now, read data back from the stream until you get the `\r\n\r\n`.  Then, you can disconnect.  Check the status code from the first response line and see if it's `200`.  If it is, you've got an active stream.